# Property does not exist on type 'string' - iterate in nested Json objects

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to iterate over these nested objects and store the outer objet key and the inner nested object values in arrays so I can show them in chart.js group bar chart.

```
let goodArray = [];
let notgoodArray = [];
let fruitsArray =[];

const obj = {
 "oranges": {
    "good": 1,
    "not_good": 0
 },
 "apples": {
     "good": 1,
     "not_good": 0
 },
 "grapes": {
     "good": 2,
     "not_good": 0
 }
}
```

I have found a way to store the outer object key value like this

```
for (var key in this.obj) {
  fruitArray.push(key);
}
```

Which returns the fruit array like this

```
['oranges', 'apples', 'grapes']
```

But I can't access the fruits objets properties and add inside this loop something like

```
for (var key in this.obj) {
  goodArray.push(key.good);
  notgoodArray.push(key.not_good);
  fruitArray.push(keyname);
}
```

It returns me an error saying

```
"Property 'good' does not exist on type 'string'"
```

I need an array for the 'good' to be like

```
[1,1,2]
```

and the 'not_good' to be like

```
[0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the object:

```
for (var key in this.obj) {
  goodArray.push(this.obj[key].good);
  notgoodArray.push(this.obj[key].not_good);
  fruitArray.push(key);
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, your IDE should be able to tell you the error as you are using TypeScript.

Comment: I will check into that. Thanks for the advice